# Spell Check in IE

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

In Firefox, if a user enters words which have spelling mistakes, the browser puts a line below the word indicating a spelling mistake. How can the same be accomplished in IE ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Not a programming question.
Try googling for spellcheck IE... The first result may be useful.

Comment: @CuriousPanda - it is programming related if the OP wants to add this to IE visitors on his/her site (Say, a JavaScript solution).

Comment: @Kobi - you are right.I am looking for a javascript based approach.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to edit your question and explain that.

Comment: IE sucks,  no one should use that garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the clarification in the comments, that you want a Javascript spellcheck engine for IE...

Then the first few results for googling [javascript spell check](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=javascript+spell+check) might be what you are looking for. These give solutions like in Gmail's editor - the little red underline in Firefox/Chrome are the browser's built-in spell checkers.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer, although I would have liked to see a lmgtfy dot com link

Answer (score 1):

[Spell as you type](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellayt) plug-in for jQuery.